# Efficient sql subquery on same table based off datetime value

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Below I have a simple query to get all the movie ratings for today joining an "event" table and "movie" table.

```
Select e.*, m.moviename 
From Event e, movie m 
Where e.eventdate >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) 
  and e.moviekey = m.moviekey 
order by e.Ratings desc;
```

Question

In the example above, how would you retrieve the ratings from 1 week ago, and 1 month ago. So the query would return 2 extra columns RatingOneMonthAgo, RatingsOneWeekAgo,etc.

I've looked into subqueries and it's not clicking any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [CTEs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) to pull this information in (similar to using subqueries).

The following query assumes that you having ratings for every day, and no duplicates (multiple ratings for the same movie on the same day):

```
WITH cteOneWeekAgo
AS
(
    SELECT
        moviekey
        , Ratings
    FROM Event
    WHERE CAST(eventdate AS date) = DATEADD(WEEK, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
)
,

cteOneMonthAgo
AS
(
    SELECT
        moviekey
        , Ratings
    FROM Event
    WHERE CAST(eventdate AS date) = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
)

SELECT
    e.*
    , m.moviename
    , w.Ratings Ratings_OneWeekAgo
    , mth.Ratings Ratings_OneMonthAgo
FROM
    Event e
    JOIN movie m ON e.moviekey = m.moviekey
    LEFT JOIN cteOneWeekAgo w ON e.moviekey = w.moviekey
    LEFT JOIN cteOneMonthAgo mth ON e.moviekey = mth.moviekey
WHERE e.eventdate >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
ORDER BY e.Ratings DESC
```

I also wrote a more complex query, which will pull in the most recent ratings for the movie before the date you're looking for if ratings for that date don't exist.

```
WITH cteOneWeekAgo
AS
(
    SELECT
        moviekey
        , Ratings
        , eventdate
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                moviekey
                , Ratings
                , eventdate
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY moviekey ORDER BY eventdate DESC) R
            FROM Event
            WHERE CAST(eventdate AS date) <= DATEADD(WEEK, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
        ) Q
    WHERE R = 1
)
,

cteOneMonthAgo
AS
(
    SELECT
        moviekey
        , Ratings
        , eventdate
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                moviekey
                , Ratings
                , eventdate
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY moviekey ORDER BY eventdate DESC) R
            FROM Event
            WHERE CAST(eventdate AS date) <= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
        ) Q
    WHERE R = 1
)

SELECT
    e.*
    , m.moviename
    , w.eventdate Ratings_OneWeekAgo_MostRecentDate
    , w.Ratings Ratings_OneWeekAgo
    , mth.eventdate Ratings_OneMonthAgo_MostRecentDate
    , mth.Ratings Ratings_OneMonthAgo
FROM
    Event e
    JOIN movie m ON e.moviekey = m.moviekey
    LEFT JOIN cteOneWeekAgo w ON e.moviekey = w.moviekey
    LEFT JOIN cteOneMonthAgo mth ON e.moviekey = mth.moviekey
WHERE e.eventdate >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
ORDER BY e.Ratings DESC
```

Comment: You will want to replace `getdate()` with `cast(getdate() as date)`, to avoid omission of early morning transactions.

Comment: You're right - also for the `=` statements - thanks!

Comment: thank you. There is one minor cut and paste mistake, on your second left join it should be cteOneMonthAgo instead of cteOneWeekAgo. thanks again